# idxmin() исключение при применении

Tags: python, pandas

DF:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  KEY
1  0 65 95 80 49  11
2 65  0 78 69 16   9
3 95 78  0 55 88   6
4 80 69 55  0 87  18
5 49 16 88 87  0   2
```

Применяю:

```
df[1].idxmin()
```

Получаю исключение:

```
reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Series.idxmin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) не работает для строк (dtype: `object`), поэтому сначала преобразуйте столбец к числовому типу:

```
In [39]: df.dtypes
Out[39]:
1      object        #  <---- строковой тип данных
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
KEY    object
dtype: object

In [40]: pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').idxmin()
Out[40]: 1
```